# cant resolve domain name in bind

Tags: bind

can someone shed some light on this please, i cant seem to resolve my domain `foo.com`

```
root@dns:/etc/bind/zones# nslookup foo.com
Server:     192.168.1.54
Address:    192.168.1.54#53

*** Can't find foo.com: No answer
```

my forward zone file

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA    ns.foo.com. admin.foo.com. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.foo.com.
ns      IN      A       192.168.1.54

;also list other computers
www     IN      A       192.168.1.54
```

my syslog file

```
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: starting BIND 9.8.1-P1 -u bind
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: found 1 CPU, using 1 worker thread
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: using up to 4096 sockets
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jun 10 23:20:57 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: listening on IPv6 interfaces, port 53
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0, 192.168.1.54#53
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: sizing zone task pool based on 7 zones
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: using built-in root key for view _default
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: Warning: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone foo.com/IN: loaded serial 1
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 2
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: running
Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 2)
```

you can see here `foo.com` is loaded. and my `/etc/resolv.conf` is also been configured to `nameserver 127.0.0.1`

`Jun 10 23:20:58 zild-ubuntu named[13703]: zone foo.com/IN: loaded serial 1`

Comment: The "no answer" means DNS isn't responding to the query. Is iptables set properly? Also, try `dig foo.com @127.0.0.1` on the server. You may need the dnsutils package if not installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have no A record for `foo.com`, you only have an A record for `www.foo.com`.

Try dig with www.foo.com or add `@  IN  A  192.168.1.54` to the zone file.